# Using a loop in a batch file to convert all occurences of a backslash into a forward slash

Tags: bash, batch-file

I am sure their are options using sed or other programming languages but I would like to keep this final step as simple as possible.  It has to be run on several systems all of which have a Windows/Dos OS.  This would be the last step in a multi-stage batch file that performs several specific tasks using "oldtext.txt" as input and ending with "newtext.txt".

The final output text file though has a single backslash on every line that needs to be converted to a forward slash.  I need a way to add one more line to the script to convert that single "\" to a "/" so that no line in the file has a "\" anywhere.

Every loop I have tried ends up with an error or fails to do anything and with all the rest working perfectly I hate to start all over using a different method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
set "var=%var:\=/%"
```

would be useful?